# How to combine all .SCSS files imported to different JS components and output them to a single .CSS bundle?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, sass, webpack-4

I'm working on a project that utilizes plain JS (no frameworks) and SCSS and bundling it all with Webpack.

The structure is roughly like this:

```
│   index.html
│   index.js
│   webpack.config.js
│   
├───build
│       app.bundle.js
│       bundle.css
│       error.bundle.js
│       index.html
│                   
└───src
    ├───components
    │   │   App.js
    │   │   
    │   └───ErrorMessage
    │           error.scss
    │           ErrorMessage.js
    └───style
            footer.scss
            header.scss
            index.scss
            reset.scss
```

My only entry point is `index.js` that initializes the application. `index.scss` is imported in `App.js`.

It all worked well before I moved the styling for ErrorMessage to a separate component.

Here's my webpack configuration:

```
const path = require('path');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');

module.exports = [{
  entry: {
    app: ['@babel/polyfill', './index.js']
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    chunkFilename: '[name].bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build')
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              plugins: ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties'],
              presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: 'bundle.css',
            },
          },
          { loader: 'extract-loader' },
          { loader: 'css-loader' },
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
              plugins: () => [autoprefixer()]
            }
          },
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
              sassOptions: {
                includePaths: ['./node_modules']
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
}];
```

What I'm trying to do is import the styling for that component directly to `ErrorMessage.js` but still have it compiled to `bundle.css` and keep the single entry point. However, when I run the webpack build, it only compiles `error.css` to the `bundle.css` file.
Is there a way to parse all the .scss files like that?

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem if so please mark my answer as accepted. Thank you

Comment: Sorry, I've commented that it doesn't work for me because I want to try solve this without creating additional entry points.

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you just create 1 entry point scss file then include everything into that scss file ? Then you just need to import that entry file into your js file

Below is my [webpack](https://github.com/SaiGonSoftware/Awesome-CMS-Core/blob/master/src/AwesomeCMSCore/AwesomeCMSCore/webpack.config.js) config for your reference

```
plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: "[name].css",
            chunkFilename: "[id].css"
        })
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [{
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    {
                        loader: "css-loader",
                        options: {
                            minimize: true,
                            sourceMap: true
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "sass-loader"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment Tony. I'm new to webpack and web-development in general. So I'm not sure if what I'm trying to do is feasible. But I'm trying to avoid additional entry points to achieve the best modularity.
If I had to add more modules to my application, I would like to just import the JS-file where it's required and have all the styles parsed by webpack automatically, without importing them separately to index.scss. I'm pretty sure it's doable with .CSS, but I'm struggling to achieve this with .SCSS.